# Log standard out to file in airflow

Tags: stdout, airflow

I want to save the standard out from my dag separately from the logging that airflow generates.

My scripts print to standard out and I want to capture that (and only that) into a specified log file each time it runs.  I've tried

```
logfile = 'mylog_01.log'

myfunc = def()...

log = open(logfile, "ab")
sys.stdout = log

print_params = PythonOperator(task_id="print_params",
                          python_callable=myfunc,
                          provide_context=True,
                          dag=dag)
```

... but std.out is reset within each PythonOperator.  How do I control where standard out is printing to within all python operators?

Also, I am using hundreds of print statements within the scripts so modifying each of those isn't practical in this case.